# Heroku [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) troubleshooting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku

I'm deploying my rails backend/react frontend app to heroku. And I've come across this error on pushing to heroku master:

```
remote:        Both npm and yarn have created lockfiles for this application,
remote:        but only one can be used to install dependencies. Installing
remote:        dependencies using the wrong package manager can result in missing
remote:        packages or subtle bugs in production.
remote: 
remote:        - To use npm to install your application's dependencies please delete
remote:          the yarn.lock file.
remote: 
remote:          $ git rm yarn.lock
remote: 
remote:        - To use yarn to install your application's dependences please delete
remote:          the package-lock.json file.
```

I deleted the package-lock.json file but when pushing to heroku master again I got this:

```
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

What is the problem? Did I skip a step after deleting package.json?

Comment: The heroku remote is not set. https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/adding-a-remote

Comment: @TinNguyen I did that, it gave me

git@heroku.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app
git clone the heroku remote with this command. Then you will have on your local git repository the heroku remote set. Then add the GitHub remote using the `https://` URL not the `git` URL.  
You will have to log into heroku using the heroku CLI.

Comment: Nevermnd, added a new ssh key and it worked.